# Why my sonar measure data is nearly all zero after installing soucemeter plugin

Tags: sonarqube, measure

I  am a student know sonar just few days ago because I need to measuring the cohesive and couling of my project.I installed sourcemeter plugin,it won’t work with the lasetest version of sonar,the result it generate is nearly all zero.When I use the version 4.2 adding a custom widget which show me LCOM5, it shows “no data”.Should I configure anything other than result directory and source meter location to get it ? And the result dir indeed have a cdc contain all the data I need,but I don’t know why it won’t show in sonar.

Comment: It seems it can only be display in the hotspot widget because it is only measured for classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SourceMeter plugin is not an official plugin from SonarSource nor a community plugin of the SonarQube plugins forge. So you might use it but there's no guarantee that it will correclty work with the latest versions of SonarQube.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried version 4.3.3 and it worked.